# Stylesheet for Android

Tags: android, stylesheet, android-webview

We are making parts of our application in HTML5 in order to abstract out common functionality for Android and iPhone. When the user navigates to a WebView we want it to feel like we are still using native code.

For iOS we found [iWebKit](http://snippetspace.com/projects/iwebkit/), it was easy to import and gave the web page that iPhone look and feel. But we found nothing good for Android.

I know the theme on certain Android devices could be different which complicates having a single stylesheet. But does anyone know of anything good? Btw, it does not have to be free.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android webview performance is very poor.
I have been using jQuery Mobile Beta1 in android webview, now we decided to port back to native.
Native is still 300% faster and stable, where javacript <--> java interface is broken in Android 2.3+ gingerbread, communication between webview and context failure.

Ticket here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987

I suggest to stick with Native :)

Comment: Although, not the answer I was looking for, I appreciate the response, it was very helpful. We built most of our prototypes in 2.2 and they worked, and your right our prototypes crashed on 2.3. Thanks for the heads up before we start doing any production code.

Comment: Based on the features that are currently unavailable for webapp and the issues that you pointed out, we decided to go Native for the most part. HTML5 is just not ready yet.

Comment: Hi Alex,

If your html/javascript is hosted externally, you can still reuse it to host mobile.yourapp.com to support other mobile platform :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [sencha](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/)? It might prove helpful.

Comment: Sencha had some nice features, but not enough to complete our application. The Android stylesheets were way too simple.